# Joint boundedness of solutions of a family of Sturm-Liouville ODE

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations, sturm-liouville-theory

Let us fix $0 \neq \lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. Let us consider the following ODE, on $[0,\infty)$: $$ y^{\prime \prime} (x) + \frac{r e^{-x}}{(1+e^{-x})^2} y(x) = -\lambda^2 y(x).$$ Here $r \ge 1$ is a parameter. Let us consider the solution $e_r (x)$ which satisfies $e_r (x) \sim e^{i \lambda x}$ as $x \to +\infty$. How would one approach showing (if this is indeed true) that $$\sup_{\substack{r \ge 1\\ x \in [0,\infty)}} |e_r (x)| < \infty.$$ Ideally, I am interested in some wider class of examples, so I am less interested in a "trick" that happens to work in this very particular case, and more in some conceptual approach, but still would like to hear all approaches.

Thank you

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I try to plot this numerically, with lambda = 1 and time incrementing from 0 to 3000 with 3000 steps. Problem is I don't know to plot with boundary constraint being at infinity. So I try boundary constraint at 0: y = 0, y'=1. Impression is that, for any given r, all peaks are roughly at same height (and actually as I increase r the height decreases under these initial conditions). So roughly speaking, normalizing so that it is of height 1 at infinity, seems I do get some independence of r.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think this might well be true. A simple toy model for your situation that can be solved explicitly would be to replace the potential $-re^{-x}/(\ldots )$ by $V(x)=-r$ for $0\le x\le 1$ and $V(x)=0$ for $x>1$, and the Jost solution is uniformly bounded in this case. The key seems to be that while $|V|$ does get large, it is negative, which has roughly the same effect as making the energy $\lambda^2$ large, and the Jost function (like everything else in the spectral theory of this operator) should have well defined large energy asymptotics.

Comment: On the other hand, if you changed the sign of the potential term, then this would clearly be false.

Comment: One more perhaps not so helpful thought: The (standard, constructed via the $m$ function) spectral measure has density $\lambda/|e(0,\lambda)|^2$ on $(0,\infty)$, and the asymptotics as $\lambda\to\infty$ are $\simeq\lambda$. So if I'm right about your question being similar to large energy asymptotics, then this seems to indicate that the question could be rather delicate. (A bounded $e$ is nicely consistent with the known asymptotics, but a just slightly unbounded $e$ might be possible too, at least from this point of view.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is bounded. Moreover, $|y(x)|\leq 1$ for $x\geq 0$ for all $r>0$ and $\lambda>0$ (so the estimate is uniform not only in $r$ but in $\lambda$ as well).

This is a special case of the following theorem due to User @Fedja.

Theorem. In the equation $y''+V(x)y=0$, let the potential $V$ be decreasing and
bounded from below by a positive constant. Then every
real solution $y$ has
has an infinite increasing sequence of zeros $x_n\to+\infty$, and if $$
m_n=\max\{|f(x)|:x_n\leq x\leq x_{n+1}\}$$
then the sequence $m_n$ is increasing.

Proof. The infinite sequence of zeros is a well-known fact.
Let $x_n$ be such a zero. Suppose that $f'(x_n)>0$. We compare $u(t)=y(x_n+t)$ with $v(t)=-y(x_n-t)$. Fot $t>0$ they satisfy
the differential equations
$$u''+V(x_n+t)u=0\quad\mbox{and}\quad v''(t)+V(x_n-t)v=0.$$
and the same boundary conditions at $t=0$. Since by assumption
$V(x_n-t)\geq V(x_n+t)$, Sturm's compasrison theorem gives that
the smallest positive zero $t_0=x_n-x_{n-1}$ of $v$ is at most the smallest positive zero of $u$, and on the interval $(0,t_0)$ we have $u(t)\geq v(t)$. So $$m_{n-1}=\max\{v(t):0<t<t_0\}\leq \{\max|u(t)|: 0<t<t_0\}\leq m_n.$$

The result for your problem follows since $e^x/(1+e^x)^2+\lambda^2$ is decreasing for $x>0$, while $\limsup_{n\to\infty}m_n=1$ for both real and imaginary parts of your solution, due to your  normlization.

Comment: Dear  Alexandre, thank you very much for the solution! I still need to read it more carefully. Would you mind if my collaborator and I will send you via email our precise question? It is some, hopefully small, generalization of this question.

Comment: Also, not clear to me that you can use Eulers integral representation, since b-1 is very negative, maybe should use an appropriate contour integral instead.

Comment: I re-accepted it, but I don't think there is a need to actually delete it, it adds some insight.

Comment: @Sasha: I replaced my incorrect solution by a correct one.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to understand details tomorrow. But it seems, if I understood correctly (need to check more carefully), that you explain that boundedness holds if V is decreasing, while using the technique from Pinelis's answer one can see that boundedness holds if V is increasing, so that the example that people seem to like, of a periodic potential, is "of a different nature".

Comment: As stated, the theorem is false. The solutions have infinitely many zeros if and only if $-d^2/dx^2-V(x)$ has infinite negative spectrum, which need not be the case for a positive decreasing $V$. Of course, this doesn't matter in the actual application since we have $V\ge\lambda^2$ here.

Comment: @Christian Remling: Thanks. I corrected the statement.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I think that you should add to the formulation that $V$ is decreasing? Also, maybe this is trivial, but how do you see $u(t) \ge v(t)$? What I find under "Sturm's comparison theorem" online only has the statement about the first zero.

Comment: @Sasha, Actually I use an easier form of Sturm: if $f(a)=g(a), f'(a)=g'(a)$, and both functions are positive on $[a,b]$ and $f''/f>g''/g$ then $g>f$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\tb}{\tilde b}$Let us write $b,t,x,k$ instead of $|\lambda|,x,y,r$, respectively, so that for real $t\ge0$
\begin{equation*}
    x''(t)+V(t)x(t)=0, \tag{-1}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
    V(t):=b^2+g(t),\quad g(t):=\frac{k e^{-t}}{(1+e^{-t})^2}. \tag{0}
\end{equation*}
Let us show that for all real $t\ge0$ and $k\ge0$ we have
\begin{equation*}
    |x(t)|\le C(b)(|x(0)|+|x'(0)|), \tag{1}
\end{equation*}
where $C(b)>0$ is a real number depending only on $b>0$.

If $|x(0)|+|x'(0)|=0$, then $x(t)=0$ for all $t\ge0$, so that (1) is trivial. So, without loss of generality $x(0)\ge0$, and $x'(0)>0$ if $x(0)=0$.

Then, by [Theorem1](https://u.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZBBo9XZ179neeC5jkzzbVy6nJB6wYsLi2Py) (used with $a=0$ and $b_*=b$, since $V(t)\ge b^2$), for the smallest positive zero $t_1$ of $x$ we have
\begin{equation}
t_1\le\pi/b<\infty. \tag{2} 
\end{equation}
It is now clear that the roots $t_j$ of $x$ in $(0,\infty)$ form a strictly increasing sequence: $t_1<t_2<\cdots$. Moreover, by (-1) and (0), $x$ is concave on each of the intervals $[0,t_1], [t_2,t_3],\dots$ and convex on each of the intervals $[t_1,t_2], [t_3,t_4],\dots$.

By inequality (13) of the mentioned paper, we have
\begin{equation*}
    |x(t)|\le\sqrt{x(0)^2+x'(0)^2/b^2} \tag{1a}
\end{equation*}
for $t\in[0,t_1]$ if $x'(0)>0$, whence (1) holds.
On the other hand, if $x'(0)\le0$ (while of course $x(0)\ge0$), then, by the concavity of $x$ on $[0,t_1]$, $x$ is decreasing on $[0,t_1]$ from $x(0)$ to $0$, so that (1) is trivial in this case. Thus, (1) holds on $[0,t_1]$ in any case.

Inequalities (2) and (1a) were based on the trivial estimate $V(t)\ge b^2$, which can be improved for $t\in[0,t_1]$ to
$$V(t)\ge b^2+ke^{-t}/4\ge b^2+ke^{-t_1}/4\ge b^2+ke^{-\pi/b}/4=:\tb^2,$$
in view of (2), with $\tb\ge0$.
Next, by (-1), (0), and (1a) with $\tb$ in place of $b$, $|x''(t)|\le(b^2+k)\sqrt{x(0)^2+x'(0)^2/\tb^2}$.

If now $x'(0)>0$, then $x'(s)=0$ for some $s\in[0,t_1]$, and hence, in view of (2) with $\tb$ in place of $b$,
\begin{equation*}
    |x'(t_1)|\le(b^2+k)\sqrt{x(0)^2+x'(0)^2/\tb^2}\,\pi/\tb\le C_1(b)(|x(0)|+|x'(0)|), \tag{3}
\end{equation*}
where $C_1(b)>0$ is a real number depending only on $b$.
Similarly to (1a), for $t\in[t_1,t_2]$ we get $|x(t)|\le\sqrt{x(t_1)^2+x'(t_1)^2/b^2}$;
but $x(t_1)=0$; so, for $t\in[t_1,t_2]$
\begin{equation*}
    |x(t)|\le|x'(t_1)|/b\le C(b)(|x(0)|+|x'(0)|) \tag{4}
\end{equation*}
by (3), where $C(b):=C_1(b)/b\in(0,\infty)$, so that $C(b)$ depends only on $b$.

Similarly to (4), for all natural $j$ and all
$t\in[t_j,t_{j+1}]$ we get $|x(t)|\le|x'(t_j)|/b$.

So, it remains to show that $|x'(t_{j+1})|\le|x'(t_j)|$ for all natural $j$. In turn, in view of (-1) and because $g(t)$ is nonincreasing in $t\ge0$, inequality $|x'(t_j)|\ge|x'(t_{j+1})|$ immediately follows from

> **Lemma 1:** Suppose that $f\colon[0,1]\to\mathbb R$ is concave and twice differentiable, $f(0)=f(1)=0$, and we have the implication
> \begin{equation*}
>     0\le s<t\le1\ \&\ f(s)=f(t)\implies f''(s)\le f''(t). 
> \end{equation*}
> Then $0\le -f'(1)\le f'(0)$.

It remains to prove this lemma.

Comment: Dear Iosif, thank you very much, this looks very good! I will try to understand all details tomorrow, as it is night here. Just a question now: Is it clear that your inequality (1) implies what I wanted? You bound in terms of values at 0... Sorry if this is trivial.

Comment: @Sasha : It should be clear that the bound must depend on the initial conditions. The crux here is that the bound does not depend on $k$ (your $r$) or $t$ (your $x$).

Comment: Thank you, I will think about it, but I have the "initial" condition at infinity, that $x(t) \sim e^{i \lambda t}$, so a-priori could be that it forces $x(0),x'(0)$ to be larger and larger as $r$ gets larger, and therefore your estimate will not yield the estimate I want...

Comment: (maybe, once I will understand your arguments, I can "reverse" them and give bound in a point at the past in terms of bound at a future point (?), and thus see that if $x(t) \sim e^{i \lambda t}$ then $x(0),x^{\prime} (0)$ can't be too big)

Comment: @Iosif Pinelis: Sorry, I do not see how your result is related to the question:-) Your estimate depends on $y(0)$ and $y′(0)$. (And numerical computation from your other answer indicates that solutions tend to a very small when $x→+\infty$). But in the question, normalization is at ∞, namely $y(x)∼e^{iλx}$. To achieve such behavior at infinity, you need to take HUGE $y(0)$ or $y(1)$.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko : Before seeing Sasha's comment on this answer, I had not perceived the condition $x(t)\sim e^{i\lambda t}$ for large $t$ as an initial condition at $\infty$, or even as any essential restriction at all, I guess because (i) all solutions here are oscillatory, as shown in my answer and (ii) I could hardly attach the usual meaning ($a\sim b\iff a/b\to1$) to $\sim$ in $x(t)\sim e^{i\lambda t}$. The argument in this answer, concerning going from $t=0$ to $t=\infty$, is mainly based on the claim $|x'(t_j)|\ge|x'(t_{j+1})|$.

Comment: Previous comment continued: To go back, from $t=\infty$ to $t=0$ we need to prove a partial reverse of inequality $|x'(t_j)|\ge|x'(t_{j+1})|$; that is, we need to show that $|x'(t_j)|-|x'(t_{j+1})|$ is small enough. For these reasons, I think it may make sense to keep this answer, which also provides other details. As for my other answer, see my response to your comment on it.

Comment: Dear Iosif, thank you. Although your argument doesn't seem to work in that case, I learned from it.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Dear Iosif, I might be wrong, but seems that in your Lemma 1 one should have the opposite conclusion $|f^{\prime}(0)| \leq  |f^{\prime} (1)|$. Then your argument works "in reverese", to bound the function on all $[0,\infty)$ if we know bounds of it and its derivative near $+\infty$. So probably your solution is as good as the one in Eremenko's answer (I guess roughly equivalent in some sense, but not sure).

Comment: @Sasha : I think the lemma holds in the right direction. Consider e.g. $f(x)=(2-x)(1-x)x$.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematica can solve this ODE, in terms of the hypergeometric function (click on the image to enlarge it):

[image]

(By rescaling, without loss of generality $\lambda=1$.)

We now find the solution $Y$ with $Y(10\pi)=E(10\pi)$ and $Y'(10\pi)=E'(10\pi)$, where $E(x):=e^{ix}$ (Mathematica has difficulties computing values of $Y(x)$ for $x>30$):

[image]

Here are graphs of $|Y|$ with $r=1$:

[image]

and also with $r=100$:

[image]

This seems to suggest that your conjecture is true.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko : I do not understand this comment. In particular, I do not know what you meant by "normalized at $0$". Anyhow, these pictures suggest the following: for both $r=100$ and $r=1$, the moduli of both solutions oscillate with a small amplitude about a strictly positive value for large $x$. For small or moderate $x$, the moduli become only smaller than (but of the same order of magnitude as) the moduli for large $x$. In this description, I do not recognize anything I see in your comment.

Comment: what do you mean by "both solutions"? How do you choose them?  (Any solution can be multiplied by a constant.) The question is about that (unique) solution which is $\sim e^{i\lambda x}$ as $x\to\infty$. What do your pictures show about THIS solution?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko : (i) The two solutions are as described in the Mathematica notebook: obtained by choosing $(c_1,c_2)=(1,0)$ and $(c_1,c_2)=(0,1)$ in the general solution. (ii) How do you know that a solution with $y(x)\sim e^{i\lambda x}$ exists? is unique? (iii) Where did you see "very small for large $x$"?

Comment: 1. Why a solution with $y(x)∼e^{i\lambda x},x→∞$ exists and is unique. This is a general result of scattering theory (see the books I referred to). Roughly speaking, for large x the equation is essentially $y′′+\lambda^2 y=0$. Each solution of this last equation corresponds to a solution of the original equation which is close to it, by a kind of perturbation argument.

Comment: To make a convincing plot one needs to go  far to the right, so that the regime $y(x)\sim e^{i\lambda x}$ is reached. I would do this: 1) Choose r. 2) Choose $x_0$ so that the term with $r$ is very small. Start solving numerically backwards from this $x_0$, with initial condition $y(x_0)=0,y'(0)=\lambda$, and plot the result on $[0,x_0]$.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko : "On graphs number 2,4,6,8 I see a solution which is extremelly small, and whose behavior on the right side of the graph is inconsistent with the required behavior at infinity." I do not see any substantial difference between graphs 1, 3, 5, 7 and graphs 2, 4, 6, 8. The patterns look very similar in both series of graphs. The only difference is in the vertical scaling -- $\asymp1$ vs. $\asymp10^{-6}$, which is clearly quite inessential. So, I still do not understand where you saw "very small for large $x$": the values everywhere are smaller for small/moderate $x$.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko : "I would do this: [...] Start solving numerically backwards". Of course, this makes sense. However, this answer is about the exact general solution. You are welcome to consider such numerics.

Comment: Since your graphs do not show the correct behavior for large $x$, they are inconclusive. I withdrew my earlier remark that they "show the opposite". It is possible that the conjecture is true, but so far I have no proof of this.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko : (i) Of course, we do not have a proof, and it is nowhere stated in this answer that we do. (ii) I now see that you did withdraw your comment that the graphs "show the opposite". (iii) I still do not understand the insistence on "your graphs do not show the correct behavior for large $x$". The graphs suggest small oscillations of the magnitude for large $x$.

Comment: Previous comment continued: According to what you previously said, a certain linear combination of the two solutions will have a magnitude $\sim1$ for large $x$, as wanted. The graphs suggest tame behavior of both solutions for moderate and small $x$, even for large $r$, and so, one can expect such tame behavior of the solution in question (unless there is some exceptional cancellation), and tame behavior of the solution in question for moderate and small $x$, even for large $r$, is of course the main problem here. So, the graphs do appear suggestive.

Comment: These cannot graphs cannot be correct. The potential is integrable, so we know that all solutions are asymptotically a linear combination of $e^{\pm i\lambda x}$ (all real solutions look asymptotically like $c\cos (\lambda x + \alpha)$).

Comment: @ChristianRemling : Alas, Mathematica has difficulties computing values of solutions $y(x)$ for $x>30$. It is possible that the asymptotic pattern obtains only for values of $x$ significantly greater than $30$. Anyhow, now we have graphs of $|Y|$ for the solution $Y$ with $Y(10\pi)=E(10\pi)$ and $Y'(10\pi)=E'(10\pi)$, where $E(x):=e^{ix}$. Those graphs "asymptotically" look much more like the graphs of $|E|=1$.

Comment: @IosifPinelis: That's definitely the case for large $r$, since you obviously need to wait until $V$ is small before you can enter the asymptotic region.

Comment: @IosifPinelis: Of course, exactly this is what the question is about (how large is $c$ in my comment above for a solution normalized at $x=0$)...

Comment: @ChristianRemling : Good point about large $r$ needing large $x$ for the asymptotic pattern. I had this in mind, but then forgot to mention it.

Comment: Just a remark: a very similar equation $y''+(re^{-x}+\lambda^2)y=0$ can be reduced to Bessel, and its solutions on $[0,+\infty)$ are indeed bounded independently of $r$. This suggests that the answer to the question might be positive, but I still have no proof.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko : Thank you for the your comment.

Answer (score 0):

There is another method, which is the "almost explicit" approach.
Write your problem under the form
$$
\frac{d^2 y}{d^2t} + \left(\lambda^2+rq(t)\right)y=0.
$$
Suppose $q\in C^4([0,\infty))$ and bounded this is satisfied by your problem of course. It turns out that there is a problem very close to this one which has an explicit solution, namely the two fundamental solutions are
$v_1$ and $v_2$ are given by
\begin{eqnarray*}
 v_1(t) &=&\sqrt{\frac{C(\lambda,0)}{C(\lambda,t)}}\cos\left(\lambda \int_0^t C(\lambda,s) ds\right)+ \frac{1}{2\lambda}\frac{dC}{dt}(\lambda,0)\frac{1}{C(\lambda,0)}v_2(t),\\
 v_2(t) &=& \sqrt{\frac{1}{C(\lambda,0)C(\lambda,t)}}\sin \left(\lambda\int_0^t C (\lambda,s) ds\right).
\end{eqnarray*}
You note that $$v_2(0)=0, \quad \frac{dv_2}{dt}(0)=1, v_1(0)=1, \frac{dv_1}{dt}(0)=0,$$
and an explicit calculation shows that
$$
\frac{d^2v_i}{dt^2} +\tilde q v_i =0
$$
with
$$
\tilde q = \lambda^2 C -\frac34 \left(\frac{1}{C}\frac{dC}{dt}\right)^2 + \frac{1}{2C}\frac{d^2C}{dt^2} 
$$
Now choosing $C$ wisely, you obtain "almost" $\lambda^2+rq$, and so your solution is almost the correct one.  You can make simple choices, such as
$$
C=\frac{1}{1-\frac{r}{2\lambda^2}q(t)}
$$
which gives
$$
\tilde q = \lambda^2 + rq(t) + \text{residual terms}
$$
the residual terms being bounded by $\frac1{\lambda^2}$ when $\lambda$ is large. In your particular example, if you compute what the remainder is, it is very well behaved, and so this is just a scattering estimate around a known profile, which in this case would be $v_1+iv_2$, since $C\to1$ at infinity.

The WKB method (in geometric optics) inspired choice is
\begin{equation}
A= \left(1+ \frac{r}{\lambda^2}q\right)^{-1/4}, \quad B =- \frac{1}{4} A^{3} \frac{d^2 A}{d t^2},\mbox{ and } C = \frac{1}{(A (1+\frac{1}{\lambda^2} B))^2}.
\end{equation}
In that case, you find that
$$
|\tilde q - (\lambda^2 + rq)| \leq \frac{K}{\lambda^2}
$$
where $K$ is controlled by the $C^4$ norm of $q$ (and is exact if $q$ is a polynomial of degree three, I think I remember)-- I assumed you where interested in something uniform in $\lambda$.

The point is that the fundamental solutions of your original problem are now very well approximated by these explicit (and bounded) solutions, for arbitrarily large $\lambda$.

---

To explain where this all comes from (WKB), try to solve the initial equation with  solutions of the form $A(t)\exp(i \lambda \phi(t))$. You find $$y^\prime = A^\prime \exp(i \lambda \phi) + i \lambda A\phi^\prime \exp(i \lambda \phi),$$ and $$y^{\prime\prime} = (A^{\prime\prime} - A \lambda^2(\phi^\prime)^2) \exp(i \lambda \phi(t)) +  i \lambda (2 A^\prime \phi^\prime +A \phi^{\prime\prime})\exp(i \lambda \phi).$$
So this imposes $2 A^\prime \phi^\prime +A \phi^{\prime\prime}=0$, which means $A=\frac{K}{\sqrt{\phi^\prime}}$. Then you want to solve $$
A^{\prime\prime} - A \lambda^2(\phi^\prime)^2 = -(\lambda^2 +rq)A,
$$
that is,
$$
\sqrt{\phi^\prime}\left(\frac1{\sqrt{\phi^\prime}}\right)^{\prime\prime} - \lambda^2(\phi^\prime)^2 = -(\lambda^2 +rq).
$$
In the development above, $C=\phi^\prime$.

Comment: Thank you. Looks like some Alchemy to me for now :)

Comment: @Sasha I have added a paragraph explaining the WKB Alchemy. Should have started with that perhaps.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to read.