# Boundedness of solutions to second order ODE

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations, fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $q(x)$ be a probability density function over $[0,1]$. Let $\lambda > 0$ and $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be any solution to the following ODE:
$$
\lambda f''(x) + q(x) f(x) = 0, \text{for all }x \in [0,1]; \\
f(0) = 0; \\
\int_{0}^{1} x f(x) q(x) dx = \lambda f(1); \\
\int_{0}^{1} f^{2}(x) q(x) dx = 1.
$$
Does there exist an absolute constant $C$ such that any solution pair $(\lambda, f)$ satisfies
$$
\sup_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x)| \leq C?
$$

Special case: This conclusion holds true for $q(x)=1$, i.e., the uniform distribution. Under such circumstances, the solution pair is given by $(\mu, \sqrt{2}\sin(x/\sqrt{\mu}))$, where $1/\sqrt{\mu}=\frac{2k+1}{2}\pi$ for $k\geq 0$. As one can see, all the solutions are bounded in magnitude by $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Could you explain why you want to know that / why you think it is true, what you tried so far to establish it, etc?

Comment: You're imposing three conditions on the solution of a second order ODE, so typically one would not expect that there is such a solution.

Comment: @username Thanks for your interest. This ODE originates from the first-order Sobolev function space, namely the functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that are absolutely continuous and $\int_{0}^{1} [f'(t)]^{2} dt$ is finite. Given any distribution over [0,1], one can find eigenbasis associated with the function space under the distribution; guaranteed by Mercer's theorem. The ODEs above correspond to the eigenequations. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercer%27s_theorem

Comment: @ChristianRemling Thanks for your reply. As I explained above, the ODEs orginate from Mercer's theorem. The existence is guaranteed. The uniform distribution (i.e., $q(x)=1$) is often used in textbooks to show that all the eigenfunctions $f(x)$ is bounded. I'm wondering if this boundedness property still holds regardless of the distribution being used.

Comment: For small $\lambda$ (large $k$), the method suggested [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/394585/40120) should help.